# Raspbian corrupt after changing settings

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-stretch

Everytime when I change settings in the newest Raspbian Stretch image, do I get errors after the next reboot. Can someone say what's wrong and what I can do about it? I have searched on Google for the answer, but I didn't find anything working. You can see the errors below.

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2][image: Error 3][image: Error 4]

Comment: This looks like a problem with your SD card. Some blocks seem to be overlapping with others. This can happen when the SD card reports more space than it actually has. I'd give it a shot with another SD card.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try that. I will you know if it works.

Comment: @steviethecat I bought a 32GB Kingston SD Card and this one is giving no errors, thank you for the tip.